# Can't move Mesh with Armature

Tags: mesh, armature, rigidbody

I have read a lot of treads with the same problem. And I think I have tried to make everything. But Can't still get it to work.
I'm new to Blender.

Working in Blender 2.90.1

I have made a character and pressed Ctrl + J. So it's only one mesh.
Added the Armature
Parented with auto weight so the Armature is pareting the Mesh.
And when I go in to Pose-mode and click on a armature och moves it, the mesh don't follow.

Blendfile:
https://easyupload.io/ofledn

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you did the parenting thing, but your problem is fixed if you select the mesh, go to Properties > Relations and change the parent type from object to Armature.

[image]

Re-parenting everything all over again, it works fine!
[image]

Comment: Also, I noticed that the lower spine doesn't move with the respective bones, even after the fix, even though the arm works ok. You might want to re-parent the mesh to the armature all over again!

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why it did that. :O

Next problem. :P I now made a new Armature and made it work with that. But some parts seams like they are stuck and don't move. Like the head. When I move the armature for the head only the "hair" is moving. How is that?

Thank you for your patience!

https://easyupload.io/v0f54c

Comment: That just means that some portions of the mesh weren't assigned to any bones, so they're stuck. 
But I couldn't understand why, so I just cleared all of the parenting on your mesh (there were two Armature modifiers at the same time, for some reason!) then selected the mesh, shift-click on the armature, then hit ctrl-P and Armature Deform with Auto Weights, and it works perfectly. 
Obviously, the weight can be fine-tuned in weight paint mode, but it works pretty well on default. 
I dunno what you're doing different! (see new screenshot added to my answer)